# Session variable destroys on every page reload

Tags: php, apache, session

After i reload the page, $_SESSION becomes empty !
Worked fine until there was some server maintenance.

For the sake of the testing, i only have a index.php file with the lines

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['test'] = 'works';
echo $_SESSION['test']; //displays the 'works' fine
```

But as soon as i reload the page, 'test' becomes undefined, $_SESSION variable is empty.

```
echo session_id(); // changes every time
```

Does anyone knows where to look for the problem ? 
Is this an apache misconfiguration about write privileges or some problem with cookies ?
Im gladly hear anykind of idea

Comment: Check the error logs, check the parameters the cookie with the session id gets set with, check if the session id stays the same or changes, …

Comment: session id changes every time i reload the page. what could be the problem ?

Comment: First two thoughts -- check your browser's cookie storage to make sure it's actually storing the session cookie, and check your session storage directory to make sure the owner of the web server process can write to it.

Comment: can you help me how to do that ? i checked firefox manage cookie menu, it sais the page has 13 Cookies thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is permission to write in session file.
View error log for error if any exist.

Comment: error log is empty. How can i check the session file permission ? i do have a CPanel access

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. Answers are for solutions, not for questions. If you don't have enough rep to comment yet, work on that instead of bypassing the rep restrictions this way.

Comment: @Ninet9 it should be inside apache log directory as error.log and access.log as default

Comment: @MagnusEriksson actually Jumper was answered and was not asking. Do you see question mark in his answer ? Thank you Jumper for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP sessions cookies are set for the current session. When you refresh, you get a new sessionID because it is a new cookie.

Try extending the lifetime of the session cookie by using the code below and rename "mydomain" :-) (this is assuming you are using session cookies: see PHP documentation on this. If you are using something else to manage your sessions, check there)

```
    session_set_cookie_params((60*60*24*31), '/', '.mydomain.com'); //setting for 31 days 
    session_start();
```